# Possible issue with Anti Mosquito apps emitting high frequency noise

Tags: windows-8, audio, lenovo-laptop

I downloaded(out of curiosity) an [Anti-Mosquito application](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-in/app/anti-mosquito/00c62406-00de-4418-b3e8-29c932439292) from Windows store a couple of weeks ago for my laptop(Lenovo Y560) which emits what they call a "very unique and high frequency sound" or "Ultra Sound" to keep mosquitoes away. I used the app at a frequency between 10 kHz and 20 kHz for testing purposes.

I used the app at 10 kHz and it emitted a continuous beep noise. When I toggled it to 20 kHz it made some popping noise (like kit kit) which was not loud but clearly audible and within 5 seconds I could smell something burning from my laptop. I have hardly used the app for around 5 times or so in the past month and when I play anything on my laptop now - It plays the audio/video file but I also hear a crackling noise with it. There is also a burning smell when the speakers runs for more than 3-4 mins. My drivers are fine because the headphone is OK.

P.S. - I am only *interested* to know if this app emitting the high frequency noise has or may have caused an hardware issue and not suggestions on *how can I use a fan to keep mosquitoes away*. Thanks.

Comment: Pain is nature's way of saying "Don't do that!"  In your case the smell is the same thing.  You're overloading your speakers -- they simply can't handle that much sustained high frequency sound.  Keep in mind that "power ratings" for most amplifiers and speakers are "peak" ratings, not "average" ratings, and they should never be driven at full power indefinitely.  The defect is in the app, for not explicitly warning you of this.  By now you've probably fried something.

Comment: Support link for the App points to a hotmail address.  App description is rife with spelling and grammatical errors... I think those should have been giant red flags that quite possibly this App wasn't tested all that well.  You had no guarantee or warranty for using this App to use your laptop in a manner that wasn't intended.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - I agree with you and I shouldn't have installed this app in the first place. Also the laptop now emits the smell even when I am not playing anything so yeah something is already fried or still frying. I would however like to say that Microsoft or any company for that matter should not allow apps that are not tested thoroughly to be uploaded on the stores.

Comment: I'm no great fan of Micro$oft, but it would be hard to test such an app in a sufficient variety of circumstances to assure that it wouldn't cause damage.  Many systems would not have powerful enough audio amps to damage the speakers that way, and, anyway, most testing is directed at weeding out malware and software that would tend to corrupt your system.  (As it is, I suspect your speakers have been fried.)

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like a hardware fault. (Dodgy soldering/wire? Beyond abilities of the speakers (Shouldn't be)?) 
Boot from a bootable linux disc and test the speakers, to rule out software/driver issues.
Beyond that: back to manufacturer if it's still under warranty, or else screwdrivers + soldering iron are probably in order...

(Not to kick you when you're down, but there is no solid evidence that ultrasonic noise repels mosquitoes. Just, y'know...in case you were considering re-installing the software after the issue is fixed.)

Comment: I am not going to reinstall the software by any means. I really don't think if this is dodgy soldering/wire because whenever I used the s.w @ 20 kHz it emitted that noise along with that smell - It never did that before though. However I am not ruling out the possibility though.